# Как в PyQt5 организовать вывод ошибок в консоль?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, исключения

Делаю учебное приложение на *PyQt5*. В целом приложение работоспособно, но время от времени "падает" по непонятным причинам.

Есть ли способ получить **`Traceback`**  в консоль?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы должны использовать `excepthook`, 
и если вы хотите, чтобы событие завершилось, вы должны вызвать метод quit().

```
import sys
import traceback
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class ErrorApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        bar = self.menuBar()
        menu = bar.addMenu('&Menu')

        action_raise = QtWidgets.QAction("Raise", self)
        action_exit = QtWidgets.QAction("Exit", self)
        menu.addAction(action_raise)
        menu.addAction(action_exit)

        action_exit.triggered.connect(self.quit_trigger)
        action_raise.triggered.connect(self.raise_error)

    def raise_error(self):
        aa = 5 / 0                                        # какая-то ошибка           

    def quit_trigger(self):
        QtWidgets.qApp.quit()



def excepthook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
    tb = "".join(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb))
    print("Oбнаружена ошибка !:", tb)
#    QtWidgets.QApplication.quit()             # !!! если вы хотите, чтобы событие завершилось


sys.excepthook = excepthook

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = ErrorApp()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Ваш пример работает. Но, насколько я понимаю, данная функция применима только к той части кода который выполняется на python. Если ошибка возникает в C++ части QT, то о причинах можно только догадываться?

Comment: @СергійСитюк я не пробовал вариант, который вы написали в комментарии. Если мой ответ вам чем-то помог, не забудьте отметить его как полезный.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/incompatibilities.html#unhandled-python-exceptions

> ... an unhandled Python exception will result in a
>   call to Qt’s qFatal() function. By default this will call abort() and
>   the application will terminate. Note that an application installed
>   exception hook will still take precedence.

Comment: Если я правильно понял "доку" функция qFatal() относится к части кода на с++?

Comment: да. так-то питон сам выплёвывает эксепшены в stdin. Так что ответ @S-Nick более информативен